# Using sinon how does one fake/stub/mock a non existing JS API in a way than sinon.restore removes all trace of it afterwards?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

While running my tests I sometimes want to provide a API for my tests. I want this api to be defined for the duration of the test(s) alone, and so I want to ensure that `sinon.restore()` removes this test api. This is not replacing an existing JS API. (eg. NOT something like `window.requestAnimiationFrame`). This API is assumed to exist globally. (eg. on the global/window object)

Now If I didn't care about removing this API, after the test was done I would do the following:

```
globalAPIObject.someTestApi = sinon.fake.returns('something');
```

However `sinon.restore` won't/can't remove globalAPIObject.someTestApi after the test has run.

I would like to be able to use fake, in the same way as `stub`. (but sinon doesn't provide this)

```
// !! this API doesn't exist !!
sinon.fake(globalAPIObject, 'someTestApi').returns('something');
// !! this API doesn't exist !!
```

So I use stub instead:

```
// This doesn't work if globalAPIObject.someTestAPi doesn't already exist.
sinon.stub(globalAPIObject, 'someTestApi').returns('something');
```

However this only works for replacing props/functions that already exist, so I have to do:

```
globalAPIObject.someTestApi = () = {};
sinon.stub(globalAPIObject, 'someTestApi').returns('something');
```

Which is less than ideal. (As globalAPIObject.someTestApi isn't removed at the end of the test, by sinon.restore(). Also I'd rather only have to write a single line)

Since I guess that providing a non existent API is something that lots of people want to do, I guessing I'm missing something obvious.

**What is the best way to fake/stub/mock a new API in a way than sinon.restore removes all trace of it afterwards?**

Comment: Not sure I understand your use case. Why do you want to stub/fake a non-existing API?

Comment: @Christian - in the production environment, the api in injected into the JS environment. This doesn't exist in the test environment. I would like to provide it using sinon, to gain isolation between tests, rather than doing it manually,

Comment: If you know its signature why not just use a stub for it like `{ theNonExistingMethod() { return 'something' }}`? Why is this less than ideal?

Comment: @Christian - If I stub in manually not using sinon, then it persists beyond that test. a single api might by stubbed differently depending on the test. I don't want a stub api, that was done for one test to be available for other tests. If the writer of the tests forgets to stub the needed api, I want it to fail, every time, not be dependant on the order the tests were run.

Comment: @Christian - but I see that "less than ideal" isn't obvious, so I will add more reasons. Thanks.

Comment: I'm probably still missing something but couldn't you just do: `const theStub = sinon.stub().returns('something');` or will that still be around after `restore`?

Comment: @Christian - that works for local vars/const. But in this case the API is assumed to exist globally. eg. window.theStub = ... instead of const theStub = . I guess this isn't clear. I will update question. Thanks

Comment: Not very pretty, but how about forcibly delete the method in `afterEach`/`after`: `delete globalAPIObject.someTestApi`?

Comment: @Christian - yes that would work. But was hoping that there was a way I could make sinon.restore() could do that for me...

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot do this using `sinon.restore()`. We explicitly made the API throw on trying to replace non-existent props, but we have had a longer discussion about this on the sinon team and essentially [came to the the conclusion that we should add something like `sinon.define()`.](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2195#issuecomment-590048688) Still, no one ever *made* that feature request into an actual issue, so if I were you I would just file a new issue with this as your feature request to the Sinon Github tracker. Lots of people would like this feature and it's really not that hard to implement, so just make it visible :)

To actually do this using today's existing machinery I would probably just do as mentioned in the comments: use your test frameworks before/after hooks to setup and tear down manually constructed stubs.

If I were to do it myself I would probably have redone the code to be able to inject the API into your module, though, instead of relying on globals. That's another school of thought, so, whatever rocks your boat :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that 'oligofren' helpfully clarified that sinon.stub doesn't our use case yet we just extended it so does.

```
// sinonExtensions.js

import sinon from "sinon";

if (sinon.stub !== enhancedStub)
{
    sinon.originalStub = sinon.stub;
    sinon.stub = enhancedStub;
}

function enhancedStub(obj, method)
{
    if (!obj)
        return sinon.originalStub();
    if (!obj[method])
        obj[method] = () => { };
    return sinon.originalStub(obj, method);
}

// TODO: enhance sinon.restore to return non-existing methods to undefined
```

Which we just import along with the rest of the sinon imports:

```
import sinon, { mock } from "sinon";
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
import 'sinonExtensions.js';

chai.use(sinonChai);
```

Which is good for all our current usages of sinon.stub.

And now this happy works:

```
sinon.stub(globalAPIObject, 'someTestApi').returns('something');
```